# Why jshell allows non-final free variables in lambda expressions?

Tags: java, lambda, final, jshell

In a `.java` file, following will not compile:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        Runnable r = () -> System.out.println(x);
        r.run();
        x++;
        r.run();
    }
}
```

However in jshell, this will work and the  output of the first `r.run()` is `0` and for the second, it is `1`. So I want to know how is `x` accessible to `r`?

Comment: Err, because they screwed up? If it departs from the JLS, it's wrong. What kind of an answer are you actually expecting here?

Comment: I just wanted to know if I am missing out on something from java. If this is a deviation then I don't care about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This's how jshell actually works:

```
class $1 { int x; static void run() { x = 0; } }
class $2 { Runnable r; static void run() { r = () -> print($1.x); } }
class $3 { static void run() { $2.r.run(); } }
class $4 { static void run() { $1.x++; } }
class $5 { static void run() { $2.r.run(); } }
```

Every time you enter a new command, jshell defines a new class and wraps it as a static method.

You can see the actual class name using `new Throwable().printStackTrace()`

Comment: Now I understand it. Thanks